# strcat 3 char from char[] to char * works on Windows, but gives segmentation fault in Cygwin

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I need to update an older application, where now "Type" needs to be dynamicly set based on the 2nd till 4th letter of a filename:
I quickly hacked following code that works perfectly on Windows, but gives a  segmentation fault in Cygwin:
First of "Type" is defined in x.h as

```
private:
    CHAR* Type;
```

The Code:

```
INT32   Engine::Run(...)
{
    Type = new char[4];
    strcpy(Type,"");

    char FileName[50];
    char *pscL;
    char Unit[4];
    strcpy(Unit,"");
    pscL=strrchr(File1,'\\');
    char *ps = pscL;
    ps++;
    ps++;
    memcpy(Unit,ps,3);
    Unit[3]=0;
    if (strcmp(Unit, "AAA") == 0)
    {
        strcpy(Unit,"AAA");
    }
    else if (strcmp(Unit, "BBB") == 0)
    {
        strcpy(Unit,"CCC");
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(Unit,"BBB");
    }
    strcat(Type,Unit);
    printf("Type: %s \n",Type);
    ...
    //furtherdown Type is used in eg.:
    if (strcmp(Type, "HCU") == 0)
    ...
    if (!GetFile(calRet,Anal,pC,fcN,Type)) return -1;
    ...
```

File1 is in the form of "D:\tmp\testing\yada\XBBBYYYYY123YYY.ZZZ"

The strcat(Type,Unit); gives an segmentation fault. I don't want to change the type of "Type" since this is used all over the place, code I don't want to touch.
I'm very limited what I can do in the cygwin installation (where it should run when finished) to debug, which is why it frustrates me that it works on Windows.

Comment: Are you sure the paths use the same slash in cygwin and Windows?

Comment: Use std::string, don't use str* functions.

Comment: This code looks awfully fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
pscL=strrchr(File1,'\\');
```

you should check pscL value against zero, after doing that:

```
if(pscL == 0)
{
  pscL=strrchr(File1,'/'); //unix style file path on cygwin
}
```

This is because, [as explained here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Cygwin_002fWindows-File-Name-Conversion.html):

> Cygwin provides a Unix emulation environment for Windows. As part of
>   that emulation, it provides a file system mapping that presents the
>   Windows file system in a Unix-compatible manner.